# how to install db2 v10.5 on windows10?

Tags: windows, db2

I want to install db2 express in windows 10.
I downloaded the db2 but when I run the installer says that "you can not run this app in your pc" what should I do?
thank you

Comment: Use a supported OS. Check following page for details http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27038033

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the downloadable package, though it is an `.exe` file, is in fact a simple PKZIP archive. Renaming the file from `.exe` to `.zip` and using the Windows archive extractor worked for me.